# How to launch server side script (bash script) when toggle checkbox is set to On/Off with django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm actually trying to set a on/off toggle but I don't know how to execute a script on django which is located in /opt/script/interfacestatus.sh.
What I want to do is that when the checkbox is set to check it execute /opt/script/interfacestatus.sh eth0 up. /opt/script/interfacestatus.sh eth0 down.
Can someone help me on that.

Cordially.

views.py:

```
    user=request.user
    interfaces = Anubis_Interface.objects.all()
    output = subprocess.check_output('/opt/scripts/anubis/installinterfaces.sh', shell=True)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
            return render(request, 'registration/interfaces.html', {'interfaces': interfaces})
    else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect ('/auth')
```

interfaces.html:

```
{% for interface in interfaces %}


                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="{{interface.Anubis_Interface_id}}" onchange="myFunction('{{interface.Anubis_Interface_name}}','{{interface.Anubis_Interface.Anubis_Interface_name}}" style="display:none">{{interface.Anubis_Interface_name}}</p></td
                   <td>




{% endfor %}

<script>
function myFunction(myitems,myitems2) {
  var text = document.getElementById(myitems);
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(myitems2);
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please be a bit more descriptive so that other can understand your issue

Comment: Hello deepak, thanks for your reply.  I’ve made a checkbox. What I want to do is when someone check on that checkbox, it execute /opt/script/interfacestatus.sh eth0 up and when it goes uncheck execute /opt/script/interfacestatus.sh eth0 down. I’ m sorry for my poor english